# LUA script error: '(' expected near 'if'

Tags: lua, roblox

I was making a ROBLOX game and this happened in the output:

ServerScriptService.Script:6: '(' expected near 'if'

and the script didnt proceed
Someone help me with this,i don't know what to do.I view and review the script and i don't understand what happened.Sorry i'm still a noob at this
Here is the complete script:

[image]

Comment: please share your code, people don't know what you had done so far.

Comment: Do not change your question into a completely different one after it gets answered. Also, stop posting *pictures* of your code. Copy the script and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a function declaration must look like this `function whatever() <code> end` (line 5)

Also, after an `if` statement you need a `then` keyword (line 6)

The `end` at line 13 should be at the same height as the corresponding `if` at line 6. This will cause no errors, but it makes the code harder to understand.

Try to maintain some consistency; choose either `"` or `'` and stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a parameter list after the function name. Use `()` if it's empty.

I'd paste a full example but I'm on my phone, typing is difficult, and for some reason you chose to share your source as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 should look like this:

```
if Players > 2 **then**
```

You forgot to add then at the end.

Then at line 13,

```
end
```

should be aligned with the first word of line 6